# Are WCF service arguments automatically URI decoded?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

are WCF service arguments automatically URI decoded or do I manually do it?

Comment: Your question is vague, terse and doesn't seem to make sense. Can you give us a lot more details about what your are trying to achieve, what you have tried and what problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Terse it may be, but it makes sense to me.  URI encoding is a common need when passing data via HTTP.  It's a very simple question; perhaps that is why it seems confusing.

Comment: Please be more clear. Are you talking about SOAP or REST? What client are you using? .NET? JavaScript?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: did you notice the tags?  C# & .NET.  URI Encoding is a universal concept.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: I did notice the tags. Does ".NET" refer to the client or the service?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: of course it refers to the client. The service is the entity that is going to misconstrue stuff if it isn't correctly encoded. The Uri-encoding is what the client must do to pass special characters to the service. I'm sure this applies regardless of whether one is talking to SOAP or REST.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: it does not apply to SOAP, at least not if the client is WCF or ASMX. These frameworks do any encoding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED TO ADD:**

When I originally put forward this answer I seem to remember having verified it in a test.  Upon @JohnSaunders comment below I revisited with a new project.  And found that a console app submitting the string above returned the string exactly as it had been submitted, without having URI encoded it.  It may be that I did something unexpected previously.  Anyway, @JohnSaunders is correct.

---

**Original Incorrect Answer:**

No, they are not, and yes you have to URI encode them if you're expecting special characters.

If you were to submit this to a WCF service in the stream of data passed to it:

"http://localhost/users/email/bill@microsoft.com"

It would show up on the server like this:

"bill"

The "@microsoft" gets removed

The passed data must be URI encoded to get it all to pass through.

Comment: Thank you I am fairly new to WCF and this solved some confusion.

Comment: -1: this is not true for a WCF SOAP service called from almost any client platform.